# Duvida modificando tags HTML com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Alguém saberia me dizer como eu posso alterar uma tag html com angular, tipo como se eu adicionasse na tag um ng-model e partir disso eu pudesse alterar as propriedades da tag como class, id, texto e etc...

Comment: O `ng-switch` ajuda? http://plnkr.co/edit/VykyIo

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar sua própria diretiva para isto. Veja na documentação do angular(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), a seguinte seção '**Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM**'

Este artigo pode te ajudar também. (http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/changing-the-dom-in-response-to-user-actions.html)